# Conditional probability that 2 random $n$-element subsets of $[m]$ agree on element

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $X,Y\subset [m]$ be 2 uniformly randomly drawn $n$-element subsets of $[m]=\{1,\dots,m\}$ where $m>n$. (There are in total $\binom{m}{n}$ many such subsets.)
Denote by $X\cap Y$ the intersection of those two subsets and by $ |X\cap Y$| the size of this intersection.

Let $A$ be the event that the number 1 is in both $X$ and $Y$, i.e.
$$A:  \;\; 1\in X\cap Y$$
$B$ the event that 1 is neither in $X$ nor in $Y$, i.e.
$$B: \;\; 1 \not\in X\cup Y$$

I am looking for the following conditional probability:
$$\Pr(A\cup B\; | \; (|X\cap Y|=k))$$
i.e. the probability of $A$ or $B$ conditioned on the intersection size being $k\leq n$.

**Edit:** What I think, I know:
$$\Pr(|X\cap Y|=k) = \frac{\binom{m}{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m-n}{n-k}}{\binom{m}{n}^2}=\frac{\binom{n}{k}\binom{m-n}{n-k}}{\binom{m}{n}}$$
$$\Pr(A) = \frac{\binom{m-1}{n-1}^2}{\binom{m}{n}^2}=\frac{n^2}{m^2}$$
$$ \Pr(B)=\frac{\binom{m-1}{n}^2}{\binom{m}{n}^2}=\left(1-\frac{n}{m}\right)^2$$
and since $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive:
$$\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A) + \Pr(B)=1+2\frac{n^2}{m^2}-\frac{n}{m}$$

**2nd Edit:** I now also calculated $$\Pr(A\; | \; (|X\cap Y|=k)), \; $\Pr(B\; | \; (|X\cap Y|=k))$$ via the joint probabilities $$\Pr(A\; \cap (|X\cap Y|=k)), \; \Pr(B\; \cap (|X\cap Y|=k))$$

These are given by
$$ \Pr(A\; \cap (|X\cap Y|=k)) = \frac{\binom{m-1}{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{m-n}{n-k}}{\binom{m}{n}^2}$$
and
$$\Pr(B\; \cap (|X\cap Y|=k))=\frac{\binom{m-1}{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m-n-1}{n-k}}{\binom{m}{n}^2}$$
Hence, the conditional probabilities are given by
$$\Pr(A\; | \; (|X\cap Y|=k)) = \frac{\binom{m-1}{n-1}}{\binom{m}{n}}\frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{k}{m}$$
and
$$\Pr(B\; | \; (|X\cap Y|=k)) = \frac{\binom{m-1}{n}}{\binom{m}{n}}\frac{\binom{m-n-1}{n-k}}{\binom{m-n}{n-k}} = \frac{k+m-2n}{m}$$
Hence, because $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive the conditional probability in question is given by the sum of the individual conditionals as
$$\Pr(A\cup B\; | \; (|X\cap Y|=k)) = \frac{2k+m-2n}{m}= 1 -2 \left[\frac{n-k}{m} \right]$$

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you sort out the probability that $|X\cap Y|=k$?  CAn you work out $P(A)$, $P(B)$?

Comment: Hey, thanks @lulu for your help. See my edit, I think I worked out all those probabilities.

Comment: I agree with your computations of  $P(|X\cap Y|=n)$, and $P(X),P(Y)$.  Now, what is $P(A\,|\,|X\cap Y|=n)$?

Comment: @lulu Did you mean $P(A),P(B)$? Responding to your question: I am not sure: $ \Pr(A | |X\cap Y|=k)=k/m?$ How does this help me?

Comment: Yes, I meant $A,B$.  Note that $A,B$ are mutually exclusive, so if you can handle $A,B$ separately then you can simply add to get the union.

Comment: @lulu Hi, thanks to your help, I now think, I have got the right result. Could you tell me if it is correct if you happen to have computed it yourself?

Comment: Certainly looks good. Yields the correct result in every case I tried.  I don't have time to check the computation carefully right now, but I will later.

Comment: Yes, this looks good.  Quite a pleasant formula in the end, really.